# Picture is too late to be displayed VLC Android

Tags: android, libvlc

I used libvlc in my android application and I got it to work. The problem now is, it keeps giving me an error of:

```
core video output: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 29787 ms)
```

Using the VLC player, I don't get any lags. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: looks like a bit misconfigured video stream (not adjusted timestamps? holes in UDP? race on network?)

Comment: @snachmsm, if this is the case, then whatever VLC player I use, I would get the same result. This happens only when I am using the libvlc i used in my android application.

Comment: where are you looking for similar log in desktop VLC? run it with `-vvv` and then in GUI pick View -> Add interface -> Console. afaik logs are very similar on every platform (as the core of VLC is "shared")

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any LibVLC options? If not, you should. Here is what VLC for Android uses https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android/blob/master/application/resources/src/main/java/org/videolan/resources/VLCOptions.kt

My guess is you have not properly configured hardware decoding, which leads to the video output displaying the picture later than it should.